# How to use javascript functions in Rails UJS responses

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, function, ujs

I find myself having a lot of code which is the same in many `js responses` such as adjusting heights, and some coloration on the same class, etc.

Is there a way to put all of that duplication in a function and just call that function on each js response? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in coffeescript, you can create a global function using

```
@adjustHeights = (arg1, arg2) ->
  ... code here
```

then just call this inside the js templates